# railsプロジェクトをherokuにデプロイ出来ない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[挫折した人必見！HerokuでRailsアプリを公開する方法](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/8178)

上記のurlを参考にherokuのデプロイを試みているのですが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
rubyのバージョン2.7を入れたところ、

scaffoldで作るブログアプリを作れなくなりました。

またrubyのバージョンとgemのバージョン違いでデプロイ出来なくなりました。

どのバージョンに合わせ何を書き換えることでデプロイ可能になるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージに従ってみてはいかがでしょうか。まずは`bundle install`の実行、そして`Gemfile`内にある`ruby`ディレクティブのバージョン番号を`2.7.0`に変更、この2点を実行してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます、やってみます。